# unless и логический оператор

Tags: perl

часто, в примерах, сравнивают функцию unless как инверсию if, однако в выражении:

```
my $x = '';
my $y = 1;
unless($x && $y){ # аналогично if(!$x || !$y){
print 'ok'
}
```

оператор "&&" работает как "||"

и в

```
unless($x || $y){ # аналогично if(!$x && !$y){
```

оператор "||" работает как "&&"

это специфика или баг?
и почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не специфика и не баг. Так работает булева логика. Сам оператор "срабатывает" именно тогда, когда после вычисления всего выражения в целом получается *истина* для if, или *ложь* для unless.

В вашем примере вычисление `$x && $y` даст *истину* тогда и только тогда, когда обе переменные имеют *истинное* значение. Если хотя бы одна из них *ложь*, то и результат *ложь* и unless "срабатывает". Что абсолютно идентично выражению `!$x || !$y`, которое срабатывает когда хотя бы одно из значений ложно.

То же самое придется проделать с оператором, если вы например захотите написать `if( ! (!$x && !$y) )`

И да, это довольно тяжело до восприятия, но такова булева алгебра.

Comment: Mike, благодарю, тогда действительно проще писать так: "if(!$x || !$y" - что-бы потом не запутаться)

Comment: @usr13 Я именно так и делаю, использую unless только с одним условием ;) Потому что и мне это взрывает мозг, особенно когда условий еще больше :)

Comment: Mike, да, все именно так))